# Remove elements from an array to get array of desired length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My purpose is to create a function that removes elements from an array to reduce its length to the desired length.

But the condition is that it should remove the elements at (almost) equal interval. And the function should work for any value of array.length and desired_length.

For example:

```
myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
desired_length = 7;

myFunction( myArray, desired_length )  //returns  [0, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
```

It does not matter which elements are removed. But if we plot the elements of returned array on a line chart, then the line should be as smooth as possible.

### Use Case:

I have an array which contains images. I want to render them as GIF of fixed number of frames. So if there are 100 images in the array, I want to remove some images from between so the array has only 20 images. Now the important part is to remove frames at equal interval so the final animation is as little jerky as possible. The length of the array can vary each time.

Comment: What should happen if I call `myFunction( myArray, 7 )?

Comment: and they usually don't result in writing the _entire_ function body for the task at hand.

Comment: @Teemu Sorry about that, I'll keep that in mind next time. :)

Comment: @rlemon: I am not sure how to do the calculation of which element to remove hence I didn't write it in there.

Comment: @xzoert: Updated the question.

Comment: The point of my and rlemon's comments is, that you should show what you've tried to solve the problem. "_I need a function_" you can say to a programmer you've hired, we're not here to do all your job for free.

Comment: @Teemu: I didn't write what I tried to do because it was not working. But I understand your point now that it made my question look like I was lazy to find the solution myself. So I'll be careful next time. Thanks again.

Comment: You're wellcome. A non-working code is exactly what we're waiting for, there wouldn't be any idea with posting some working code ; ).

Comment: @Teemu: Updated the question and posted my solution as an answer. Any suggestions or better solution are most welcomed :)

Comment: with your update question, you change the requirement. for example, the first requirement was to drop some of the items, like every second item for getting 10, now you like to keep the first and the **last** and distribute the rest inbetween. for the first request, you could into account an algorithm, like the euclidean algorithm, which spreads a number of items equally over a given area.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the remainder operator and check for zero with the division of the length of the aaray and the wanted length.

```js
function getArray(array, length) {
    return array.filter(function (_, i, a) {
        return !(i % (a.length / length));
    });
};

var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

console.log(getArray(myArray, 10)); // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18] 
console.log(getArray(myArray, 5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Neat solution... ;o)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nina. However, this solution does not work for myFunction( myArray, 7). Actually, my exact problem is that I am not able to figure out how to calculate which elements to remove when array.length % desired_length is not 0. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is the calculation of `step` which can be used to iterate over the original array.

**EDIT:** adding `Math.round` makes the code work for `length / desired_length != 0`. Your desired output is hard to reproduce in my eyes.

```js
myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

console.log(myFunction( myArray, 10 )) // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18] 

console.log(myFunction( myArray, 5 )) // [0, 4, 8, 12, 16] 

console.log(myFunction( myArray, 7 )) // [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]

function myFunction( arr, desired_length) {
    var arr_length = arr.length;
    var step = Math.round(arr_length / desired_length);
    var new_arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_length; i += step) {
      new_arr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return new_arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ppasler. However, this solution does not work for myFunction( myArray, 7). Actually, my exact problem is that I am not able to figure out how to calculate which elements to remove when array.length % desired_length is not 0. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Update your question with the desired output for 7

Comment: I've updated my answer, but the output doesn't give the things you wanted, as they do not follow any logic in my eyes.

Comment: Yeah, I know my question is not quite clear. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Is there any logic which values are picked from the list?

Comment: I have updated the question and posted my solution as an answer. I hope it makes sense now. Any suggestions are most welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
// always saves first and last element
function setMaxElements( array, max_elements ) {
    if( array.length > max_elements ) { 
        // Always save first element
        var new_array = [ array[0] ];

        // index of last saved element
        var last_saved_element = 0;

        for( var i = 1; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            // (array.length-1) & (max_elements-1) because we already saved one element
            var element_group = Math.floor( i / ( array.length - 1 ) * ( max_elements - 1 ) );

            if( last_saved_element < element_group ) {
                new_array.push( array[i] );
                last_saved_element = element_group;
            }
        }
        return new_array;
    } else {
        return array;
    }
}

myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 13 ) );  // [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19]
console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 10 ) );  // [0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 07 ) );  // [0, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 03 ) );  // [0, 10, 19]
```

*For my use case I decided to keep the first and last element and remove from the rest. If that is not a constraint for you, then you can also use this function:*

```
//  always saves first element but may remove the last element
function setMaxElements( array, max_elements ) {
    if( array.length > max_elements ) { 
        var new_array = [];
        var last_saved_element = -1 ;
        for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            var element_group = Math.floor( i / array.length * max_elements );
            if( last_saved_element < element_group ) {
                new_array.push( array[i] );
                last_saved_element = element_group;
            }
        }
        return new_array;
    } else {
        return array;
    }
}

myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 13 ) );       // [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19]
console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 10 ) );       // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 07 ) );       // [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
console.log( setMaxElements( myArray, 03 ) );       // [0, 7, 14]
```

---

*I put the values in excel to understand how to create the formula.*

[image: Understanding the formula]

---

*Final result*

[image: Final result]

As you can see, The function converts the array of any length to the desired length.